# how to add format plain text to Outlook command line parameters

Tags: outlook, command-line-arguments

in my code . i'm using cmd to start outlook:
`cmd /c start outlook /c ipm.note /m "onakajima@a-i-s.co.jp;?cc=;&subject=【依頼】見積依頼について&body=aaa"`

[start outlook with command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFtmZ.png)

But it start with format **html**

[outlook init with mode format html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru7ci.png)

I want to sart cmd with this code and auto  open outlook start with mode: **plain/text**

can anyone help me pass agrument to cmd to open open outlook start and auto select with mode: **plain/text** ?

[start init out look with plain text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM8S7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook command line doesn't provide all the options as command line switches. Instead, you may try using the [mailto protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) which opens a client's e-mail system and begins a new email message. For example, the following example shows a link that will prepare an e-mail message:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?
    subject=MessageTitle&amp;
    body=Message Content">
    Contact Us</a>
```